# Lightning:recordForm custom buttons

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, aura, lightning-record-form

Is it possible to include custom buttons on Lightning:RecordForm or any of its variations ? Specifically a "save and new" button.

If this is not possible, should the alternative be to create a custom button and position it so that it looks like its apart of the form?

Is there a way to suppress the save and cancel button that come with lightning:recordForm?

Comment: Hou should use lightning:recordEditForm as it is more customizable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to include custom buttons on Lightning:RecordForm or any of its variations ? Specifically a "save and new" button.

You **cannot** *inject* any buttons on `lightning:recordForm` directly. But you can always create custom buttons on the component that utilizes this component. You will though need a mechanism to interact with the fields on the record form.

> If this is not possible, should the alternative be to create a custom button and position it so that it looks like its apart of the form?

As mentioned above, you can create custom buttons to be used in your component but cannot *embed* it into the `lightning:recordForm` component itself.

> Is there a way to suppress the save and cancel button that come with lightning:recordForm?

Yes/No. Yes, only when you use `readonly` mode. No if you are using `edit` or `view` mode.

If you want custom behavior, you should instead look to use [`lightning:recordEditForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation)